# How can I disable the refreshScope health indicator in spring boot + cloud?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

I've disabled the config server health indicator with `health.config.enabled=false` but that isn't disabling the refreshScope health indicator.

[image: Actuator health check response]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

```
management.health.refresh.enabled=false
```

Comment: thanks, i was trying every permutation of refreshScope, but it was just "refresh".

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bean of `RefreshScopeHealthIndicator` and override the `doHealthCheck` method to not to throw exception. Code snippet is Kotlin, but you'll get the idea.

```
@Component
class CustomHealthIndicator(
    private val scope: ObjectProvider<RefreshScope>,
    private val rebinder: ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder
): RefreshScopeHealthIndicator(scope, rebinder) {
    override fun doHealthCheck(builder: Health.Builder) {
           builder.up()
    }
}
```